# SQL query is not working on phpMyAdmin as I am getting an error

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have entered this code on phpMyAdmin as an SQL query. I am trying to create a table (this is a copy and pasted code from another site)

```
   CREATE TABLE `members` (
`id` int(4) NOT NULL auto_increment,
`username` varchar(65) NOT NULL default '',
`password` varchar(65) NOT NULL default '',
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) TYPE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;
-- 
-- Dumping data for table `members`
--
INSERT INTO `members` VALUES (1, 'john', '1234');
```

I get the error

"#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'TYPE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=2' at line 6 "

Comment: write create query only then execute it. After creating table execute insert query

Comment: @LokeshJain That doesn't solve the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be ENGINE not TYPE to specify the storage engine:

```
CREATE TABLE `members` (
`id` int(4) NOT NULL auto_increment,
`username` varchar(65) NOT NULL default '',
`password` varchar(65) NOT NULL default '',
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;
```

see [CREATE TABLE syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table.html):

> table_option:
>       ENGINE [=] engine_name

The option TYPE was removed with MySQL 5.5, deprecated since MySQL 4.0:

> The older TYPE option was synonymous with ENGINE. TYPE has been
>   deprecated since MySQL 4.0 but is still supported for backward
>   compatibility in MySQL 5.1 (excepting MySQL 5.1.7). Since MySQL 5.1.8,
>   it produces a warning. It is removed in MySQL 5.5. You should not use
>   TYPE in any new applications, and you should immediately begin
>   conversion of existing applications to use ENGINE instead. (See the
>   Release Notes for MySQL 5.1.8.)

Source: [CREATE TABLE, MySQL 5.1](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html)