# How to solve sql import error #1064 with query (joomla)

Tags: mysql, sql, joomla

I want to import my sql to my host for this I delete database and joomla then upload new joomla site and create new database and user last night...

when I upload sql I get **error** `#1064` with this query:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `vnmbl_assets` (
`id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Primary Key',
`parent_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Nested set parent.',
`lft` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Nested set lft.',
`rgt` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Nested set rgt.',
`level` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'The cached level in the nested tree.',
`name` varchar(50) NOT NULL COMMENT 'The unique name for the asset.\n',
`title` varchar(100) NOT NULL COMMENT 'The descriptive title for the asset.',
`rules` varchar(5120) NOT NULL COMMENT 'JSON encoded access control.',
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
UNIQUE KEY `idx_asset_name` (`name`),
KEY `idx_lft_rgt` (`lft`,`rgt`),
KEY `idx_parent_id` (`parent_id`)
) TYPE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=360 ;

MySQL said: Documentation
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax;
        check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version
        for the right syntax to use
        near 'TYPE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=360' at line 14
```

When I **changed** '`TYPE:MyISAM`' to '`ENGINE:MyIsam`' errors a bit get less:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `vnmbl_finder_tokens` (
`term` varchar(75) NOT NULL,
`stem` varchar(75) NOT NULL,
`common` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`phrase` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`weight` float unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
`context` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '2',
`language` char(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
KEY `idx_word` (`term`),
KEY `idx_context` (`context`)
) TYPE=MEMORY
```

Please Help me to fix it my host get died now...

Comment: You changed it from "type" to "engine". Good. So now what's the problem?

Comment: Change in this very old script any occurence of `TYPE=<storage engine type>` to `ENGINE=<storage engine type>` TYPE was deprecated since MySQL 4.0 and is removed since MySQL 5.5, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25949054/sql-query-is-not-working-on-phpmyadmin-as-i-am-getting-an-error/25949112#25949112

Comment: thanks for your replies... but i want fix errors still stick(second codes bar) how can I fix that... please help me

Answer (score 0):

Open up the .sql file, do a search for "TYPE=MEMORY" and replace all with "ENGINE=MEMORY"